# Create Custom form field similar to Tag form field type

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, tags, custom-field

I want to create a custom field : **hobby** similar to TAG form field except one thing. I want to create this custom field for my component and therefore want to save the `hobby field` values or tags in my own component table.

Currently, I am using:

`<field name="hobbies" type="tag" mode="ajax" label="Hobbies" description="" multiple="true" custom="allow" required="true" />`

By doing so, I am able to store custom tags but they are stored in `#__tags` table. I want to change this and save it to my table `#__component_tag`

Kindly, guide me on this